# Discord.js return message reply embed

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
if(message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "övgü")) {

        var c1 = message.content.split(" ")

        if(c1.length < 3) {
            return message.reply({content:"**Lütfen bir steam64ID ve miktar giriniz.**"})
        }

        var steam64ID = c1[1];
        var steamidResolver = require("steamid-resolver");

        steamidResolver.steamID64ToFullInfo(String(steam64ID), (err, info) => {
            if(err) return message.reply({content: "**Lütfen geçerli bir steam64ID giriniz.**"});

    client.channels.cache.get(config.channel).send({content: `~commend ${steam64ID} ${count}`})
    return message.reply({ content: "nice"})
```

Here, when command is sent as a message, it tags the user who wrote it and gives a "nice" reply as a message, how can I embed it?

Answer (score 1):

```
client.channels.cache.get(config.channel).send({content: `~commend ${steam64ID} ${count}`})

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('nice')
.setDescription('nice')
.setColor('<your color>')

 return message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
```

Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: yes but giving error, not responding as embed

Comment: Can you show what error it says?

Comment: gives message in the  `if(err)`  code

Comment: edit your post with your whole code with error

Comment: it gives content in `if(err)`  code as the answer

Comment: i edited post now

Comment: How can I write embed message instead of content, like this: `return message.reply({embeds: title: "nice"})`

Comment: not title i want, `return message.reply({ embeds: [{title:"nice"}]})` I replaced content with this code, but it doesn't work correctly, it gives spaces as an reply

Comment: your embed title is `embed` so you need to call your embed reply as `{embeds: [embed]}`

Comment: but not reply as embed